# Vlookup on other tab, using formula (left()) for tab name

Tags: excel-formula, tabs, range, vlookup

I have a series of drawing numbers, with the first 3 characters being the unit. I have tabs with the tab name as the unit.

EG: drawing - 003/123, tab name 003.

I need to look up the drawing number on the relevant unit tab and return a value. I assumed this would be something simple like **=vlookup(A2,"'"&left(A3,3)&"'!"&A:B,2,false)**, but it's not working. It's returning #VALUE.

Can you help? I've tried putting the A:B range in the quotes too.

So, the data would be something like...

- 001/111  A
- 002/002  D
- 003/441  Z

There's a tab for 001, 002, 003 etc. with various drawing numbers, and I want to pull the above column B from the relevant tab who's tab name is the first 3 characters of what's in column A..

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the volatile function `INDIRECT()`.

Volatile means that the formula will recalculate after any change is made in any cell of the spreadsheet - if this formula is used en masse it can cause performance issues, if this occurs manual calculation may be required.

`INDIRECT()` reads a string that represents a cell reference as a cell reference:

Your final formula will look something like this:
 `=vlookup(A2,INDIRECT("'"&left(A3,3)&"'!A:B"),2,false)`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I wondered about Indirect, but I'm not overly familiar with it and thought a simple left should work. Thanks for your super prompt reply!